# Outputting Tables in a GUI Using R and Shiny

Tags: r, user-interface

I am currently trying to output a filtered table once the user has determined the amount of hours available and its current location. For some reason my GUI is not displaying the table.

I am currently using a function to create the output of the GUI. The name of the function is `available_locations(current_location_address, expected_idle_time_hours)`

*ui.R*

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
shinyServer(
pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Near work Orders"),

sidebarPanel(
  sliderInput("Expected Idle Time", "Please select the expected idle time in hours: ",
              min=1,max=8,value=4,step=.5),textInput("Current", "Please Enter your Current Address")),
                #textInput("Current", "Please Enter your Current Address"),

mainPanel("Main", tableOutput("MyDF"))                   
)
)
```

*server.R*

```
library(datasets)
shinyServer(
funtion(input,output) {
current_location_address <- reactive(input$Current)
expected_idle_time_hours <- reactive(input$`Expected Idle Time`)

output$MyDF <- renderTable({MyDF<-available_locations(current_location_address, expected_idle_time_hours)})
}
)
```

My current GUI look like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrlns.png)
The output of the function "available_locations" looks like this: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX7wK.png)

Thank you

Comment: your *reactive* functions need to be denoted as `current_location_address()` and `expected_idle_time_hours()`. You also don't define what the `available_locations` function is, so we cannot reproduce your results.